# How to get sidebar to take up 90% of the page when top bar is using pixels?

Tags: css

I've got a difficult question and have spent a good half-hour researching on what to do to fix this problem but have had no luck.

As you can see the in the below, there is a small gap on the bottom left of the picture. The gap is between the side bar and the bottom of the page. The side bar uses a percentage of 90% for it's height while the top bar using a height of 60px. The reason why I am using pixels for the top bar is because I do not want it to resize when resizing the window vertically. I have highlighted the problem in a red box, here is the screenshot...

[image]

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="left">
          <div class="title">
            <p>Cold Ops</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="side-bar">
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-tachometer-alt fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="Dashboard">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-title">
          <p>TOOLS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-ban fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="Ban Panel">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="Warn Panel">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-gift fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="Gift Panel">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="User Info">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-title">
          <p>NEWS</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-file fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="New Post">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-trash fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="Remove Post">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-title">
          <p>OTHER</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button">
          <div>
            <form action="http://google.com">
              <i class="fas fa-chart-pie fa-lg"></i>
              <input type="submit" value="Game Statistics">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100vh;
}

.top-bar {
  display: flex;

  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px -5px rgba(169,169,169,0.5);
}

.top-bar .left {
  flex: 2.195;
}

.top-bar .left .title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 100%;
}

.top-bar .left .title p {
  align-self: center;

  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.top-bar .right {
  flex: 10;
  background-color: white;
}

.side-bar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  overflow: auto;

  width: 18%;
  margin-top: 1px;
  height: 89.9%;

  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 3px 0 10px -5px rgba(169,169,169,0.5);
}

.side-bar > div:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 25px;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.side-bar .button {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.side-bar .button div {
  text-align: left;
}

.button form input {
  margin-left: 40px;
  background-color: Transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.button form input:active {
  color: black;
}

.button form i {
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 2.5px;
  padding: 5px 0px;
}

.button:hover form i {
  color: dodgerblue;
}

.sub-title {
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-left: 12%;
}

.sub-title p {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #7A8B92;
}
```

**Note:** When the window is not in full-screen mode this issue does not occur.

**If you have extra time:** what do you think of the theme and my CSS code? Can it be improved? Is it good?

Comment: why not simply 100% and then padding-top:60px inside ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif I don't understand what you are saying. Where do I put the 100% and where do I have padding-top 60px?

Comment: @OmarDajani You can also set `.side-bar` `height` as `calc(100vh - 60px)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif I put the 100% in the side-bar and the padding-top: 60px in the top-bar (instead of height: 60px) and it does work but then then that makes the page scrollable and I don't want that.

Comment: @fen1x This worked perfectly! If you wouldn't mind, can you please give me a brief explanation on what calc() does? I have seen this function before and looked up the documentation to it but do not fully understand it. Thanks! :)

Comment: I mean height :100% in the sidebar and also padding in the sidebar too so that you  keep the space of the top bar

Comment: @OmarDajani `calc` simply calculates the expression inside its parentheses. That's what it does, so there won't be much more documentation about that part. Most of the pages about `calc` are about what it can't do, what to look out for etc.